# JSON property value without quote

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

peace be upon those who follow guidance,

is there a reason why not getting total property quoted? while using `JSON.stringify(this.items)` via **axios** post.

**Code:**

```
 items: [
                    { description: 'Item name', quantity: 0, price: 0, discount: 0,  get total() {
                            return this.quantity * this.price;
                        }
                        },
                    { description: 'Item name', quantity: 0, price: 0, discount: 0 ,  get total() {
                            return this.quantity * this.price;
                        }
                    }

                ],
```

**output**

```
"{"description":"Item name","quantity":"10","price":"100","total":1000,"discount":"1"},
{"description":"Item name","quantity":"10","price":"100","total":1000,"discount":"10"}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON, double quotes `"` around values indicate *strings*. Non-strings are not delimited with `"`s. Numbers have no delimiters, and the `total` property getter, when invoked (by `JSON.stringify`) returns a number, so the resulting JSON does not surround the `total` value with quotes.

Comment: is there a simple fix via js or vue to get it quoted?

Comment: If you want quotes, return a string from the getter instead

Comment: is there a reason why getting quoted value from getter on the 1st call not the 2nd one?

Comment: What do you mean? No matter whether you call `JSON.stringify` on an object once or multiple times, it should return the same thing each time (except in the rare case where a getter mutates a property, which is not occurring here)

Comment: I tested 3rd time without quote as 2nd!

I'm using admin-ajax.php from wordpress.

Comment: I don't see the code you're using, but it works as expected for me: https://jsfiddle.net/o34emhy1/

Comment: I found a push on the array in a section of js file which **doesn't return string**. thank you @CertainPerformance